# How to switch power going to SD card?

Tags: transistors, switches, power-electronics, sd

I am working on a project, where I need to switch ON and OFF power going to an SD card. What should I use?

Can I use a BC547 as a switch? Will that help?

Thanks

Comment: a switch ie on/off or remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sort of situation, I usually go for the following circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXGbCl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transistors to be used and the values of the resistors will depend on the voltages you are using. And as a bonus, the voltages for the power supply and for the command can be different!

**EDIT**:Because both voltages are the same, you can connect directly the P-MOSFET to the command. You can use the BS250.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuZ5rf.png)</sup>

You could also use an N-MOSFET on the ground path. As Colin suggested in the comments, the 2N7000 (or 2N7002 for SMD) is a good example.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVmjrZ.png)</sup>

Comment: is there any simple circuit, only with a single or two items in the circuit,by the way i am using 3.3V system

Comment: If the voltages are the same, a simple N-MOSFET will probably do. You can pull-down the command to make sure the supply of the SD card is off by default.

Comment: Which N-Mosfet? Can you please provide me any part number, which will be commonly available.

Comment: A 2N7000 is a commonly available N channel MOSFET, whether it is suitable will require you checking its parameters on it's datasheet.

Comment: I will get few 2N7000 MOSFETs from the local market and will have a try.
Thank you very much

Comment: By the way! are 2n7000 and 2n7002 are same.? i am looking for SMD part.
and i can see, second figure is switching GND signal to SD card, is that the same circuit applies to 3.3V power.?

Comment: Yes, it's a variant

Comment: In case of the 2N7000 low side switch there could be the risk that SD card is accidently powered by the IO lines.